# String interpolation not working for Ruby heredoc constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, interpolation, heredoc

I have a very long constant definition that requires interpolation (the real one is much longer):

```
const = "This::Is::ThePath::To::MyModule::#{a_variable}".constantize
```

Now, in order to make it more readable I tried to use heredocs to create a multiline string:

```
const = <<-EOT.constantize
  This::Is::ThePath::
  To::MyModule::#{a_variable}
EOT
```

But when I execute it I get a `NameError: wrong constant name`. Since the first example is working, I assume that it is related to the String interpolation?

Any thoughts on where this is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Strip All Whitespace and Newlines from Here-Document

You need to remove all spaces, tabs, and newlines from your interpolated here-document before you invoke #constantize. The following self-contained example will work:

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

module This
  module Is
    module ThePath
      module To
        module MyModule
          module Foo
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

a_variable = 'Foo'
const = <<EOT.gsub(/\s+/, '').constantize
  This::Is::ThePath::
  To::MyModule::#{a_variable}
EOT

#=> This::Is::ThePath::To::MyModule::Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

instead:

```
const = <<-EOT.constantize
  This::Is::ThePath::
  To::MyModule::#{a_variable}
EOT
```

use:

```
const = <<-EOT.gsub(/\n/, '').constantize
  This::Is::ThePath::
  To::MyModule::#{a_variable}
EOT
```

This method that create string `<<-EOF ... EOF` put `\n` on the end of line, then `constantize` can't work properly. Removed undesired character `\n, \t, \s` and all should work.

Look my test case:

```
conts = <<-EOF.constantize
=> ActionDispatch::Integration::Session
=> EOF

#> NameError: wrong constant name "Session\n"

conts = <<-EOF.chomp.constantize
=> ActionDispatch::Integration::Session
=> EOF
#> ActionDispatch::Integration::Session
```

For many lines:

```
conts = <<-EOF
=> ActionDispatch::
=> Integration::
=> Session
=> EOF
=> "ActionDispatch::\nIntegration::\nSession\n"
```

Fix it:

```
conts = <<-EOF.gsub(/\n/, '').constantize
=> ActionDispatch::
=> Integration::
=> Session
=> EOF
=> ActionDispatch::Integration::Session
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference from what I can tell by the error message?

Comment: There’s not just the final newline, the newline in between the two lines and the leading spaces also need to be removed.

Comment: for multiple  line use `.gsub(/\n/, '')` instead `chomp`